# Does basic controls (like Button, TextBlock) have xaml files implementation?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am new to UWP app development and am curious how basic controls are implemented. Do these primitive controls like TextBlock, Button, etc have xaml file implementation or do they only have class implementation? And if they have xaml implementation, how is that control built up? (using which primitive elements). Basically, I am trying to understand what is the most primitive element in xaml? We built our using Button, TextBlock, etc. How are they built?
Thanks

Update: adding image to show the options on context menu in VS document layout

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Button` has Xaml template but `TextBlock` does not.

If you want to know whether a control could be customized or it is built by other controls, there is a simple way you could check it. You could write down the control in the Xaml, then you could find the control in the **Document Outline Window** in Visual Studio. Right-click on the target control and you will see the menu. Choose **Edit Template** -> **Edit a Copy** and VS will create a default style of the target control automatically. The style will contain the ControlTemplate of the target control(if it has) and the style settings. The ControlTemplate shows how the control is built from other controls.

Comment: Thanks @Roy Li. I do not see option "Edit Style" in VS 2019. There is an option "Edit Template" that generates a template for that particular XAML control. IS it the same? Also can you give me an example of control that is built from other controls?

Comment: @user8252073 Yes, `Edit Template` is the same. You could check `RadioButton` as well. It is built by `Grid` and `ContentPresenter`.